# Hershey font "glyph number" confusion

Tags: parsing, fonts, file-format

I am trying to write a parser for hershey fonts: http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/hershey/

But I have a question. The first five characters on each line should be the glyph number, but my question is, what exactly does this number mean? Is it the unicode/ascii code for the character?

And in some hershey font files I've found, like the ones on this page: http://emergent.unpythonic.net/software/hershey
all glyphs have the same number: "12345". How am I supposed to interpret this? The glyph numbers are not unique which defeats the purpose, doesn't it? How do I know what glyph corresponds to what symbol?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, the glyph number is a local Hershey-specific thing. The page you link to has a list of files that map Hershey glyph numbers to ASCII.

And yes, if the glyph number is the same for all glyphs then the file is broken.